# Groups in Pattern compilers and Matchers

Tags: java, regex

So I am playing around with groups in Patterns and matchers and when dealing with multiple regexs in a Pattern compiler there is a particular group call I don't understand.

Here's it.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("((\\S+)(\\s+))");
        Matcher m=p.matcher("Hello people yeah");
        while (m.find()){
            String line=m.group(2);
            System.out.println("First match is "+line);
        }
```

So as you can see I have to regex in the compiler, the first one looks for non-whitespaces and the second one looks for whitespaces.

Now as far as I can understand group 0 is the whole expression, group 1 is ((\S+)(\s+)) 
group 2 is/supposed to be this (\S+) and group 3 is (\s+)

However when I call group 2, I get
Hello
people

but not yeah which is weird because if the compiler was only ("\S+") I would get
Hello
people
yeah

So yeah I don't really understand why yeah is not returned when i call group 2.

Comment: This is a terrible use of regex.  Consider reading the String api page (look for "split").

Comment: Each itteration of m.find() will match a word and a space (so to speak). The next match begins where the first match left off. There is no way group 1 will ever match 'Hello people' because after each itteration, all the capture groups are reset to empty.

Comment: @sln. Your argument is valid if OP used quantifier on whole group, and used Matcher.matches() method, and then get the group 1. In which case, he would get the group 1 from last match.

Comment: I may be wrong, not a Java expert. It could be that Dot-Net AND Java are the only engines that accumulate arrays of sub-matches. I guess this is whaat Rohit is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your regex is searching for is:

- One or more non-whitespace characters, followed by
- One or more whitespace characters.

Now, it will match twice in your string:

- *First match:*  [Group 2 - `Hello`, Group 3 - `" "`]
- *Second match:* [Group 2 - `people`, Group 3 - `" "`]

It doesn't match `yeah`, because there is no whitespace character after it. So, the match fails.

However, if you change your regex to - `((\\S*)(\\s*))`, it will also match `yeah`, because `\\s*` now matches 0 or more whitespace characters, and hence will match the 0 whitespace character too.

---

Issue with the regex apart. This problem can be easily solved with simple `String#split()` method. You don't need Matcher and Pattern class.

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

the above code splits your string on one or more whitespaces. Your array would contain now all the three words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did notice that. but then My question was more focused on matching the groups with the whole regex string. Isn't group 2 referring just to ("\\S+") or does it still check ("\\S+")("\\s+")?

Comment: @MichaelNana. Problem is, `matcher.find()` wouldn't be true, if that regex is no more matched in the string. And hence you don't get to print the group 2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you just said. I'm assmuning group 0=((\\S+)(\\s+))  group 1=((\\S+)(\\s+))  group 2=(\\S+)  and group 3=(\\s+)

Comment: @MichaelNana. It seems like, you are assuming your regex groups can be partially matched. So, even if group 3 doesn't match, group 2 should have matched. But that's not true. The whole regex pattern has to be matched. And then if the match is found, you can get groups from the match.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh Now that makes sense. So the groups are formed from the first match hence group 0. So since group 0 results in Hello people the group are returned from that only and not the whole phrase. That makes sense. Thanks man.

Comment: @MichaelNana. No you are confusing it a little. Group 0 will first match `"Hello "`, from that `Hello` is group 2 and `" "` is group 3. Then on the 2nd match, group 0 is `"people "`, then group 2 is `people` and group 3 is `" "`. But there is no 3rd match, and hence there is no group 0.